# select value in list box related value display in table

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

After select any value how can display all related data in table..

Like one selected box value display all country name when i select one country then related cites listed in table..

Comment: What have you already done and what is not working?

Comment: like http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html but i want to display all cites in table not listbox

Comment: @AbhishekPandey post some of your code, don't like to some vague site ;)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you rendered all your HTML data ( boxes with cities) you need to use javascript to alter/display some info, elements etc. Be more specific.

**EXAMPLE:** (using jquery)

```
<select id="countries">
 <option value="de">Germany
 <option value="gr">Greece
</select>

<select id="cities">
 <!-- empty for now; filled after user's selection -->
</select>

<!-- 2 greek cities for example -->
<select id="gr_cities" style="display:none">
 <option>Thessaloniki
 <option>Athens
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#countries").change(function() {
    var sel_read = document.getElementById($(this)[0].value+"_cities");
    var sel_write = document.getElementById("cities");
    for(var x=0,sz=sel_read.length;x<sz;x++) {
       sel_write.options[x] = new Option(sel_read.options[x].text);
    }
 });
</script>
```

...something like this, now you must read it and trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the cites in a hidden table and when the user select a country you display the table of cites on select use  javascript to do so